# How to display different icons in form title and in ALT-TAB window?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to have this behaviour with WinForms?

Answer (score 1):

The icon for the form is the Form.Icon property, The icon for the application (and Alt-Tab) is set in Visual Studio under Properties, Application, Resources.

Comment: Yes, but I need to change icon in alt-tab during run time.

Comment: Oh sorry - misunderstood. I've never had to do that.. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the [Form.Icon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.icon.aspx) property!

Comment: Oh ok, misunderstood your question. I thought you meant a different icon than the default icon.
But, I think, danbystrom has your solution below.